How to download a raster layer from an ESRI REST API MapServer in R?
I want to download the raster layer at this endpoint: https://coast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FloodExposureMapper/CFEM_CoastalFloodHazardComposite/MapServer/0, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify a valid query. Specifically, I want the raster and associated cell values, not merely an image with RGB values or similar.
I've tried using both the arcpullr package's get_map_layer() function:
al = tigris::states(cb = TRUE, year = 2022) %>% filter(str_detect(NAME, "Alabama")) %>% st_transform(3857)

arcpullr::get_map_layer(url, sf_object = al, bbox_crs = 3857)

and more manually constructing an API call using httr. All to no avail; I get varying "Invalid URL" or "Invalid or missing input parameters" errors, which are not particularly useful.
Any suggestions?

Can you edit to include your httr request as well? I'm not familiar with arcpullr, but you should be able to re-construct the query from the Export Map operation using your Alabama bounding box, since the operation works on the website.

Seems you have to point the url to MapServer, not a layer, like:
url <- "https://coast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FloodExposureMapper/CFEM_CoastalFloodHazardComposite/MapServer/"

al <- geodata::gadm("USA", path = "data") 
al <- terra::subset(al, al$NAME_1 == "Alabama") |>
  terra::project(y = "EPSG:3857")

a <- arcpullr::get_map_layer(url, sf_object = sf::st_as_sf(al))
a

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 400, 400, 160000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1583.956, 1583.956  (x, y)
extent     : -9966272, -9332689, 3531506, 4165088  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : file283b0482e977c 
values     : 1, 10  (min, max)

Let's plot it:
terra::plot(a)


For some reasons the raster is flipped, so let's process it a bit:
a <- terra::rast(a) |>
  terra::flip()
a <- terra::mask(a, mask = al) |>
  terra::crop(al)
terra::plot(a)
terra::plot(al, add = TRUE)


Please note, the default timeout set by {httr} might be insufficient to get the data (therefore not a proper reprex from my side). Additionally during retrieving the layer you may got warnings like:
Warning messages:
1: In get_sf_crs(sf_object) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: [rast] unknown extent 
3: [rast] unknown extent 

or forced to install {rvest} and/or {magick} package(s).
